# Good notation for expanding products of sums

Tags: summation, notation

This is a quation about notation.

While doing quantum mechanics, I am faced with expanding the following expression:
$$\Gamma_d^k |\psi \rangle $$

where $|\psi \rangle$ is an element of a Hilbert space (not important for this question). $\Gamma_d = \gamma_d \gamma_{-d}$ where
$$ \gamma_d = \sum_{m=0}^{\mu} \left( a^\dagger_{m+d} a_{m} - b^\dagger_{m-d} b_{m} \right)$$

and $a_{p}^{(\dagger)}, b_{q}^{(\dagger)}$ are annihilation(creation) operators. Hence $\Gamma_d$ is a double sum over, say, $m,m'$ which, when expanded, would contain 4 terms for each value of $m,m'$. The number of terms is then $4(\mu + 1)^2$.

My question is: what is a good notation for "expanding" $\Gamma_d^k$? How would I write

$$\Gamma_d^k |\psi \rangle = \sum_{?}^{?} \cdots \sum_{??}^{??} T$$

so that $T$ is an expression for one of the $4^k(\mu + 1)^k$ terms?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best way to expand a product of sums is to put the indices into a vector.

$$\prod_{i\in I}\sum_{j\in J}x_{ij} = \sum_{j\in J^I}\prod_{i\in I}x_{ij_i}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I notice that in each of my sums, for each value of $m$, I have two terms that I can choose: the $a$ term or the $b$ term. Is there any good way of encoding this into the expanded formula, perhaps similarly to how it is done in the binomial theorem? I.e. "choose the $a$ term $j$ times and the $b$ term $2k-j$ times" or something like that...?

Comment: Not that I can think of immediately. The two terms depend on $m$, which will be different in each bracket. So it's not really like $(a+b)^k$. And even $(a+b)^k$ can't be expanded with the binomial theorem when $a$ and $b$ don't commute.

Comment: I see! Thank you.